# SSRS report creating empty second page in PDF format only

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report that fits in one page. When saving it in PDF or Word, a empty second page is created. My borders as set to 0.25 inches. Any ideas on what can be done to prevent printing the second empty page?

Comment: That is mainly because of margin that has been set in the report property. because of that even if your report fits in the PDF page it add the extra space in the exported PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

Check for these things:

1. The report **body** width - if your report width (different than report body) is 8.5in. and you have .25in. left and right margins. Then your report body width has to be 8in. or less.
2. Page breaks - check your dataset(s) and rectangle (if any) properties to see if you have page break options checked, either "add a page break before" or "add a page break after".
3. White space - remove any white space from the bottom of your last dataset to the bottom of the report by dragging the bottom edge higher.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this extra page my moving the footer area next to the bottom of the tablix grid with zero padding in between.